# Unexpected behavior with CPAN_JSON

Tags: perl

Trying to use CPAN_JSON in the following way:

```
my $integer = 200;

JSON->new->allow_nonref->encode($integer);
```

and get the following error;

```
Can't locate object method "FLAGS" via package "B::IV"
```

Coming from:

https://metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON/backportPP.pm#L408

Running perl 5.8, I thought `B` Core packages are always included. Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit:

`perl -v | grep This`

This is perl, v5.10.1

`perl -MJSON::backportPP -le'print $JSON::backportPP::VERSION || $JSON::PP::VERSION'`

2.27200

`perl -mB -le'my $value = 1; my $b_obj = B::svref_2object(\$value); print $b_obj->FLAGS;'`

266498

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -v | grep This` and `perl -MJSON::backportPP -le'print $JSON::backportPP::VERSION || $JSON::PP::VERSION'` and `perl -MB -le'print $B::VERSION'` and `perl -mB -le'my $value = 1; my $b_obj = B::svref_2object(\$value); print $b_obj->FLAGS;'`

Comment: Note that I was able to duplicate using the last of the above commands, nor with your program (with `use JSON;` added). (I had to launch the program as follows to get the right module to be used: `PERL_JSON_BACKEND=JSON::backportPP perl a.pl`)

Comment: sorry for the late response just edited my question

Comment: hmmm. Can you confirm that `perl -MJSON -e'my $integer = 200; JSON->new->allow_nonref->encode($integer);'` produces the error?

Comment: (Also, note that you said you were using 5.8, but you're actually using 5.10.1)